# Xcode Run Error dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, iphone-sdk-3.0, dyld

tough one this.

Recently I added another target to my iPhone project to run a command line tool to create the initial database.

Since then, I started getting this error whilst running the iPhone project:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
  Referenced from: /Users/mm/Apple Development/XCode Projects/GridTest1/build/Release-iphonesimulator/GridTest1.app/GridTest1
  Reason: image not found`

`The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP).The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP).`

The bizarre thing is that this library appears to be successfully loaded earlier.

Here's some debug output generated by dyld:

`dyld: loaded: /Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
dyld: loaded: /Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit`

Checking dyld environmental variables and of course whether the framework is actually present, everything looks good:

`IPHONE_SIMULATOR_ROOT=/Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk`

Is CoreGraphics.framework here?... yes it is.

`/Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics`

To mystify things further:

1. App runs on device no problem either as release or debug.
2. Xcode 4 runs fine too either as release or debug.
3. Running in debug mode *with a breakpoint set* runs fine.

Fair enough you might say if it works ok in Xcode 4 why not just use that? Good point but you know how these problems can come back to haunt you. I don't want to leave this for now then it comes up again during submission.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Btw I have searched countless lists and posts on this and related errors. I've also tried most of the advice there, e.g. restart Xcode, clean, etc. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Have been stuck on this for ages so some help would be awesome.

Cheers,
Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you start the project in XCode 3 (or earlier) and are now working with it in XCode 4? I cannot tell you the number of frustrations I've experienced with frameworks not referenced correctly as Apple has released new version of XCode over the past couple of years. The consensus seems to be to delete your project and create a new one in XCode 4. I have taken to manually editing the XML files before but in the end something weird just keeps happening.  It may not be the "best" answer but should solve any odd framework referencing issues.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Thanks Rick. A move to XCode 4 seemed to resolve things. I guess XCode 3 was creaking at the seams doing this sort of stuff.